# Does the type of toner bought matter when refilling a toner cartridge?

Tags: printer, toner

I need to buy some toner for a HP Laser Jet 8550N, and I have discovered that you can't just buy "black" toner or "cyan" toner, instead the refill bottles are branded to specific printers, and the prices seem to vary wildly, seemingly without any distinguishable pattern.

So my question is, what makes toner A different from toner B? Can getting the wrong type damage my printer (or cartridge) in some way? Can I find toner for other printer models that would be cheaper and equivalent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much is difference between toners of different printers](http://superuser.com/questions/365203/how-much-is-difference-between-toners-of-different-printers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes depending on your model some toner can be too thick to go through the head where as some may be too thin. I'd look into what type you get in order to properly fill it.

Comment: Is there any way to know how thick or thin I may need?

Comment: Read the packaging? I don't exactly know how to do it I've just messed up like this before.

Comment: @Dudemcman Did this answer your question? P.S. I was recently at Staples and while their employees aren't all to smart they did confirm that not only will the ink clog the heads but when refilling you can also damage the microchips.